# Are our traffic statistics broken?

Tags: bug

A few days ago, our [Area 51 statistics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238/literature) listed our "visits/day" as around **1500**. Today, this statistic is listed as **25**. Our [site analytics](https://literature.stackexchange.com/site-analytics) also show a surprising drop in site traffic in the last day.

**Is this a bug, or are we really losing traffic that badly?**

Comment: For the record, I'm pretty sure it's the former. But I thought this was worth a meta post, so that anyone who's worried about this has a place to discuss it and see the answer.

Comment: On Language Learning SE, the "visits/day" dropped from 134 on 11.04 to 94 on 13.04, to 42 yesterday and just 3 today. This decrease looks suspiciously strong to me. See [LL SE](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/617/800).

Comment: @Randal'Thor same thing is showing up with Quantum Computing views -  it currently shows we have 8 per day. I sure hope it's a bug ;)

Comment: super super buggy

Answer (score 2):

There are two questions on Meta StackExchange about this:

- [Traffic isn't correctly registered on Site Analytics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308966/340816),
- [Traffic isn't updated correctly on Area51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309064/340816)

A [comment on the first question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308966/traffic-isnt-correctly-registered-on-site-analytics#comment1007414_308966) by Dean Ward,  software developer for Stack Overflow, says:

> We're investigating, we've had a number of large changes to our Google Analytics infrastructure, looks like we missed some bits...

**Update 03.07.2018**: It appears that Stack Exchange fixed the traffic statistics issue today or yesterday, at least in [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238/literature), which currently says we have 1,484 per day (very close to the 1,500 visits per day that is considered "good").

Comment: Unfortunately, historical figures are still not fixed in the [analytics](https://literature.stackexchange.com/site-analytics) (5k+ only, sorry). The graph starts in February 2018 and is zero before that.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Thanks, I did not know that. I need another 1400 reps before I can access site analytics.